# Spring JavaConfig how do I refer to beans that I have defined to create new beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Here's an excerpt from my Applications beans definition, I want to be able to refer to beans that I have defined.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.abc.config", "com.abc.config.common"})
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean(name = "AWSCredentialsProvider")
    AWSCredentials credentialsProvider() { return new AWSCredentials(/*Omitted*/); }  
    @Bean(name = "DynamoDBClient")
    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient() {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider());
        return dynamoDB;        
    }  
    @Bean S3Repository s3Repository() {
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider());
        return new S3Repository(s3);
    }  
    @Bean LevelMapper levelMapper() { return new LevelMapper(s3Repository()); }
    @Bean ImageDownloader imageDownloader() { return new ImageDownloader(s3Repository()); }
}
```

Right now what I'm doing is calling methods like `s3Repository()` in two places; this way I'll be creating two instances of the repository whereas I would like there to be only one instance across the application. Something like `credentialsProvider()` is lightweight so I don't mind a new instance being created for every bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it will only create one instance of repository. Using `s3Repository()` in your `@Bean` annotated method doesn't really call that method, but just tells the spring to inject the already created bean of type (as implied by return type of method) to the `LevelMapper` and `ImageDownloader` bean you create. So it will inject the same repository bean instance in both the beans referencing the method.

From this [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config):

> All `@Configuration` classes are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB.
>   In the subclass, the child method checks the container first for any
>   cached (scoped) beans before it calls the parent method and creates a
>   new instance. Note that as of Spring 3.2, it is no longer necessary to
>   add CGLIB to your classpath because CGLIB classes have been repackaged
>   under `org.springframework` and included directly within the spring-core
>   JAR.

Comment: Can you please point me to somewhere, where this is documented?

Comment: @nikhil Added Spring Docs reference.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that I would have been able to find that piece of the documentation on my own.